# How to speed up timeline scrubbing with FFMPEG?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, h.264, mpeg-4

I am using a software that converts a .MOV into a .MP4 video for use in the software.However, I want to be able to do this conversion outside of the software itself.

When used, the software outputs a very high-quality .MP4 which allows you to scrub through the software's timeline easily because the video is not aggressively compressed and has high i-frames which are good for random frame seeking and scrubbing.

So far any video I've tried to output in FFMPEG is very choppy to scrub through in the software. How can I emulate the .MP4 the software outputs with FFMPEG? (processing length is not an issue)

```
ffmpeg -i InputVideo123.mov -crf 10 -preset veryslow -vcodec h264 -qscale 0 OutputVideo123.mp4
```

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/16836

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-g 1` to make all frames keyframes.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx264 -crf 10 -preset veryslow -g 1 output.mp4
```